# Is this a good login and verifying users against a database practice?

Tags: c#, sql, security, authentication

I wanted to ask if what I am doing is considered a good practice for a login environment, I am creating a SaaS that wants you to authenticate against a login server in order to use the software I am creating, but I wanted to check if the approach I am having is the correct one, so I will post what I did here in order to see your thoughts on it! Thank you all in advance for your comments.

```
private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool loginSuccesful = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameTextBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor introduzca su Usuario.");
            usernameTextBox.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IntegraTDB"].ToString().Trim();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Users where Username = @Username and Password = @Password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", usernameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordTextBox.Text);                    
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    loginSuccesful = true;
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de autenticación: " + ex.Message);
            }
            if (loginSuccesful == true)
            {
                role_Extraction();
                IIdentity identity;
                identity = new GenericIdentity(usernameTextBox.Text);
                IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, _roles);
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido a IntegraT!");
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're storing user passwords in plain text.  So *no*, this is ***not a good practice***.  You're also throwing away potentially useful exception information in the `catch` block.

Comment: `select * from dbo.Users` for starters if you are only checking / returning username and password then change the query to select only the columns you need.. look at using `PrincipalContext along with some basic AD code` also what is the use of this line `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;`

Comment: With so many (correctly written) security modules available..

Comment: in this line `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameTextBox.Text))` you need a return in my opinion if it's condition is true..

Comment: this line could be changed to return a datatable `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` and if the count > 0 then you know it's a success and the while loop is unnecessary if you return a datatable your sql objects can be wrapped in a `using(){}` to take advantage of auto disposing as well read up on that when you get time as well

Comment: I am researching right now about hash and salt encryption for my User Database. MethodMan I use the line because as soon as my application is  executed it checks for the login before throwing the main window. The login just verifies the user exists and has a valid account. Thank you all for your comments, I wanted to know what I do wrong in order to improve myself.

Answer (score 2):

The above looks like you may be storing plain text passwords in the database. This should always be avoided IMO. At least some form of hashing should be employed.

A better approach would be to leverage an authentication solution such as active directory.

Comment: For an active directory solution do I need to be in the same network?

Comment: You would need network access to Active Directory, remote users could use VPN or similar. If it is a web application only the web server needs access to the ad environment. In this case a proxy should be used in the perimeter network for added security. If you tell me the architecture of the application or the model for users I can answer more completely

Comment: It is a winforms application that works in your computer but before it access it, it wants you to log into my server. That is the basic form of my application.

Comment: Then your server (i assume web/service contract) would need access to the Active directory domain.

Comment: Also if you are allowing direct SQL connections over the internet you are really asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comments Ross Worth, the sql database they access is isolated and just validates login, they have no other database even near them. I was aware I can't use the AD service because they will never be on the same network.

Comment: I do not agree with your answer regarding hashing the password. Hashed password are better than plaintext passwords, however this is not state-of-the-art. Better is hashing (e.g. using HMAC) with a user specific random salt.

Comment: Robert, thats why I said hashing of some form... but I agree.